# Getting error while trying to push to Heroku

Tags: git, proxy, ssh, heroku, firewall

When I type in "git push heroku master" I get an error that says:

ssh: Could not resolve hostname heroku.com: nodename nor servname provided, or not known

I am on my computer at work and I believe this problem has to do with proxies/firewall. Does anybody know of a way around this error in the command line? Or any other type of fix? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

try ssh'ing directly to heroku from your command line

```
 ssh git@heroku.com -T
```

if you don't get a response

```
 !  You can only access Heroku by ssh via git push and pull commands.
```

then it's connectivety issue or a firewall in the way that's blocking your requests.

Comment: in fact, start simple. Trying `host heroku.com` to make sure you're getting a positive DNS response.

Comment: I tried that and got this response....'ssh: Could not resolve hostname heroku: nodename nor servname provided, or not known'

Comment: ok i tried "host heroku.com" and got:

heroku.com mail is handled by 5 smtp01.e2k.ad.gtm.ge.com.
heroku.com mail is handled by 9 cinsmtp01.e2k.ad.gtm.ge.com.
heroku.com mail is handled by 9 alpsmtp01.e2k.ad.gtm.ge.com.

Comment: so you're getting a positive DNS response so the problem is that your network firewall/proxy is blocking port 22 which SSH uses. You're only solution is to get in touch with your helpdesk/operations to find out if they can permit ssh traffic for you.

Comment: actually - those DNS responses are completely incorrect for heroku.com, it should respond heroku.com has address 50.19.85.154
heroku.com has address 50.19.85.156
heroku.com has address 50.19.85.132
heroku.com mail is handled by 10 aspmx4.googlemail.com.
heroku.com mail is handled by 10 aspmx5.googlemail.com.

Comment: ok...this has worked for me before at work but im not sure whats wrong this time...i guess i'll have to contact the helpdesk here...thanks

Comment: yes i work at a company that is part of ge so its on their network

Answer (score 0):

please make an entry in your `~/.ssh/config` to get around this issue. No idea why your network is having issues. You may be behind a proxy and git has to be configured for that outside of your OS settings.

Hope this helps.

Comment: what do i have to put in my ~/.ssh/config file? sorry, i'm very new to all this

Comment: http://www.contentwithstyle.co.uk/content/4-ssh-config-tips-for-faster-remote-working/ checkout point #4

Answer (score 0):

I had a heap of trouble when accessing internet via my Zyxel PLA4215. When switching to wireless everything worked fine.