# cannot connect heroku - when writing heroku update - ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

i am trying to connect heroku
i downloaded heroku toolbelt and installed it .
then from the command prompt i type :

```
heriku login
```

althogh i type the right credentials (i checked!!) i get

```
!    Unable to connect to Heroku API, please check internet connectivity and 
try again.
```

I wanted to be sure its not something with authentication
so i typed :

```
heroku update
```

just to set up a connection that doesn't need a password.
i get the message:

```
!    Unable to connect to Heroku API, please check internet connectivity and 
try again.
```

i saw some answers that talked about the remote option so i did that:

```
heroku git:remote -a my-app-name
```

and i got the same response.

the internet connection is ok because the git program is able to push to github.
even when i run

```
 heroku install:something
```

it works.

so I tried to debug:

i downloaded a git bash so i can operate in unix through SSH 
and I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7366445/getting-error-while-trying-to-push-to-heroku) stack question comments and tried it:

```
ssh git@heroku.com -T
```

and got :

```
warning permanently added the RSA host key for ip address '50.19.85.132' to the list of     
known hosts.
permission denied (publickey)
```

then I tried to check DNS response:

```
ssh host heroku.com
```

and got :

```
ssh: host: no address associated with the name.
```

so i guess that my connection get blocked regardless of SSH .
i run netstat -a and it seems that port: 22 , 443 , 5000 that heroku uses are free.
i turned the firewall off and still no conection

what should i do?

Comment: Have you authenticated your toolbelt connection? Also, have you ensured it will pass through the firewall etc?

Comment: can you explain more?

Comment: the update commandd does not need user (email and password) authentication. about he fire wall - i am a beginer so i don't know much about it.

Comment: i followed the "get stated with heroku" guide and it doesn't write more then i did . i'll be glad to read about it somewhere.

Comment: The `update` command - I didn't realize this sorry. What does it do? It seems like it just installs the latest version of toolbelt? With this, have you tried closing the console & loading again?

Comment: i tried closing and reloading... about the firewall - i entered the firewall unblock menu - heroku is not specified there . is there something else that should be enabled? it seems a good option.

Comment: i am working on windows .. do i need to install some SSH software so it will work from the command prompt?

Comment: I don't think so - what are you trying to achieve with the Heroku Toolbelt? It only provides CLI access to their API -- if you just want to deploy apps, you can use the `git` CLI infrastructure if you wish

Comment: what about the firewall?

Comment: Firewall should be okay - are you using Windows 7 or 8? Either one should ask you for permission to use the Heroku CLI, which you can just agree to

Comment: i am using windows 7. what do you mean ask permission to use heroku CLI ? i am using the windows menu command prompt . the heroku commands  work from there. do i need to operate a command prompt from heroku?

Answer (score 1):

Try `heroku login` [first](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-command). It authenticates you.

Comment: nope - the authentication doesn't work.. but eve without authentication it doesn't get a connection