# Heroku connection problems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am trying to connect heroku; I downloaded heroku toolbelt and installed it, then from the command prompt I typed:

```
heroku login
```

Although I type the right credentials (I have checked that) I get:

```
!    Unable to connect to Heroku API, please check internet connectivity and 
try again.
```

I wanted to be sure it's not something with authentication
so I typed:

```
heroku update
```

Just to set up a connection that doesn't need a password.
I get the message:

```
!    Unable to connect to Heroku API, please check internet connectivity and 
try again.
```

I saw some answers that talked about the remote option so I did that:

```
heroku git:remote -a my-app-name
```

And I got the same response.

The internet connection is OK because the git program is able to push to GitHub.
Even when I run:

```
 heroku install:something
```

It works.

So I tried to debug:

I downloaded a git bash so I can operate in Unix through SSH 
and I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7366445/getting-error-while-trying-to-push-to-heroku) question' comments and tried it:

```
ssh git@heroku.com -T
```

And got:

```
warning permanently added the RSA host key for ip address '50.19.85.132' to the list of     
known hosts.
permission denied (publickey)
```

Then I tried to check DNS response:

```
ssh host heroku.com
```

And got:

```
ssh: host: no address associated with the name.
```

So I guess that my connection get blocked regardless of SSH.
I run `netstat -a` and it seems that port: 22 , 443 , 5000 that heroku uses are free.
I turned the firewall off and still no connection.

What should I do?
Iteried all other questions .. SSL , remote branch.. if anyone has something new please tell.

Comment: `ssh host heroku.com` tries to connect to a host called "host". Its failure doesn't mean ssh is blocked or anything like that

Comment: i saw a suggestion to do "host heroku.com" to check dns responce. i did "ssh host" because for the former isn't recognized

Comment: i tried all other questions its not a dup question.. i don't know how to react

Comment: Make clear what you have tried - "all the other questions" does not help people know what you have tried. Editing a question puts it in the reopen queue.

Comment: Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: i think yes i have filtered internet, but it doesn't work on other suppliers also.